# AWS Route 53 NodeJS Express Subdomain

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain, amazon-route53

We have an app made in Node JS, we created a LoadBalancer and we already run the app with Express and Forever, all works fine, when we request the URL of the LoadBalancer we have our response.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Parcel Pending API",
    "data": {}
}
```

With Code 200.

But when we create on Route53 a subdomain "subdomain.domain.com", and make an alias to point on the LoadBalancer, the subdomain doesn't work.

Our app.js:

```
require('./config/config');     //instantiate configuration variables
require('./global_functions');  //instantiate global functions

console.log("Environment:", CONFIG.app)

const express       = require('express');
const logger        = require('morgan');
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
const passport      = require('passport');
const subdomain = require('express-subdomain');
const v1 = require('./routes/v1');
const vhost = require('vhost');
const app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// app.use(cookieParser());
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());

//DATABASE
const models = require("./models");
models.sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to SQL database:', CONFIG.db_name);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to SQL database:',CONFIG.db_name, err);
});
if(CONFIG.app==='dev'){
    models.sequelize.sync();//creates table if they do not already exist
    // models.sequelize.sync({ force: true });//deletes all tables then recreates them useful for testing and development purposes
}
// CORS
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization, Content-Type');
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

app.use('/v1', v1);
app.use(subdomain('api', v1));

app.use('/', function(req, res){
    res.statusCode = 200;//send the appropriate status code
    res.json({status:"success", message:"Parcel Pending API", data:{}})
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

What we are forgetting about the configuration?
Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: After you point to the subdomain, any specific error you are getting?

Comment: Hi @Ashan, its funny because i get the message of "Would you like to buy this domain?" of directnic.com, but the DNS are already pointing to AWS.

Comment: :D. Is this a domain you have newly purchased through Route53?

Comment: We bought it yesterday on "directnic", like always we created a hosted zone with that domain and put on "directnic" the NameServers to use our domains. Do you think the DNS are still on propagation?

Comment: Seems like the domain is not yet pointing to the newly added Nameservers. Yes it can be due to propagation delay.